# An inequality about Bernstein polynomials

Tags: inequality, polynomials

We defined the Bernstein polynomials as following
$$
p_{nk} 
\ = \
\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} x^k(1-x)^{n-k}.$$

Let 
$$
p_n(x) \ = \ \sum_{k=0}^n f(k/n) \cdot p_{nk}(x).
$$

Let $f$ be continuous from $[0,1]$ to the set of real number. I have to show that

$$
\forall x \in [0,1], \qquad
|f(x)-p_n(x)| \ \leq \ \sum_{k=0}^n |f(x)-f( k/n)|.
$$

And I think I have to make use of this knowledge:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \left(x - \frac kn\right)^2 p_{nk}(x) \ = \ \frac{x(1-x)}{n}.
$$

---

**My tries**

It rewrote it in this way

$$
|f(x)-p_n(x)| \ = \ |f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n f(k/n) \cdot p_{nk}(x)|
\ \leq \ \sum_{k=0}^n \left|\frac{f(x)}{n}-f(k/n)\cdot p_{nk}(x) \right|.
$$
I would be done if I could show that the equality holds termwise, by that I mean:
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)}{n}-f(k/n)\cdot p_{nk}(x) \right|
\ \leq \ 
|f(x)-f( k/n)|.
$$

But I don't see how I could do that. Can you give me a hint to go on please?

Answer (score 1):

Write $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nf(x)p_{n,k}(x).$$
We get $$|f(x)-p(x)|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^nf(x)p_{n,k}(x)-f\left(\frac kn\right)p_{n,k}(x)\right|\leqslant \sum_{k=0}^n\left|f(x)-f\left(\frac kn\right)\right|p_{n,k}(x)$$
(noticing that $p_{n,k}\geqslant 0$). 
To conclude, we have to show that $p_{n,k}(x)\leqslant 1$ for each $n$.